# How do I set Terminal as part of my wallpaper?

Tags: command-line, desktop-background, transparency

I have spent the last few days wiping my laptop (too much "experimenting") and getting up to date with 11.10. In the process, I came across conky which I'm now playing with, and along with conky I saw some amazing desktop set-ups. Among one of these was one that had the terminal shell as a transparent almost part of the wallpaper. I would like to know how to do this so that there are no window borders or title bar. Just seamless on the background. I know how to adjust the background settings of terminal itself but not matter how transparent you make it the window still has a border. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [terminal applet for screenlets](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Terminal+Screenlet?content=74844)

[image]
or **Guake** terminal

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you! simply changed the border width to 0 and it works! now on to futz with conky